# Sorting NSArray of Custom Objects by property - DBMetadata - Dropbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I couldn't find out why sorting `NSArray` of `DBMetadata (NSObject)` doesn't work. Here is my code. What is wrong? I even tried adding a category to add `compare:` but it doesn't work.

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
    if (metadata.isDirectory) {
        NSLog(@"Folder '%@' contains:", metadata.path);
        for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents) {
            NSLog(@"\t%@  is directory? %d", file.filename, file.isDirectory);
            if (file.isDirectory) {
                [self.availableBackups addObject:file];
                DLog(@"llastModifiedDate %@", file.lastModifiedDate);
            }
        }
    }
//    NSLog(@"before sorting: %@", self.availableBackups); //lastModifiedDate //filename

    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastModifiedDate"  ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];
    [self.availableBackups sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];

//    NSLog(@"after sorting: %@", self.availableBackups);
}
```

`self.availableBackups` is `NSMutableArray`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *availableBackups;
```

Dropbox - [DBMetadata.h](https://github.com/pho0/dropbox-ios-sdk/blob/master/DropboxSDK.framework/Headers/DBMetadata.h)

Commented `NSLog` just print the address of obj, you can see the output of address is still the same after sorting regardless of `YES` or `NO` for `ascending:`

output

```
2013-01-31 17:20:12.423 Dropbox[7366:c07] before sorting: (
    "<DBMetadata: 0x6bbf010>",
    "<DBMetadata: 0x6bbfb50>",
    "<DBMetadata: 0x6bc1660>",
    "<DBMetadata: 0x6bc17b0>",
    "<DBMetadata: 0x6bc14f0>",
    "<DBMetadata: 0x6bc0dd0>",
    "<DBMetadata: 0x6bc1de0>"
)
2013-01-31 17:20:12.424 Dropbox[7366:c07] after sorting: (
    "<DBMetadata: 0x6bbf010>",
    "<DBMetadata: 0x6bbfb50>",
    "<DBMetadata: 0x6bc1660>",
    "<DBMetadata: 0x6bc17b0>",
    "<DBMetadata: 0x6bc14f0>",
    "<DBMetadata: 0x6bc0dd0>",
    "<DBMetadata: 0x6bc1de0>"
)
```

with ascending `NO`

```
Last Modified file at 0: 2013-01-30 08:00:22 +0000
Last Modified file at 1: 2013-01-30 08:02:54 +0000
Last Modified file at 2: 2013-01-31 09:08:26 +0000
Last Modified file at 3: 2013-01-31 09:14:55 +0000
Last Modified file at 4: 2013-01-31 09:14:08 +0000
Last Modified file at 5: 2013-01-31 09:16:43 +0000
Last Modified file at 6: 2013-01-31 10:36:13 +0000
```

Comment: "you can see the output of address is still the same after sorting regardless of YES or NO for ascending:" Where is the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` returns an array, it does not modify the array you're applying it on. If you need to use `NSArray`, try:

```
self.availableBackups = [self.availableBackups sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

If you can use `NSMutableArray`, you could use:

```
[self.availableBackups sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```